# Log Whatsapp conversations

Tags: logging, chat, whatsapp

We want to log everything that's being communicated with our clients.
We log e-mails, phone calls and letters.
With WhatsApp I tried different approaches already:

- Keep an app like Notisave running on Android to read notifications, export as txt and import in database. Problems: Reliability, file format, automation
- Try to access the backup file on Google Drive. Problem: File is encrypted
- Use official WhatsApp Cloud API. Problems: huge effort (We'd have to programm our own GUI and webhook)  for a seemingly simple problem, reliability of own webhook (messages could get lost when our webserver is down) and more.

I keep thinking there has to be a way I haven't thought about yet.
Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

From [WhatsApp's FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/1180414079177245/):

> ## Export chat history
>
> You can use the export chat feature to export a copy of the chat history from an individual or group chat.
>
> 1. Open the individual or group chat.
> 2. Tap **More options** > **More** > **Export chat**.
> 3. Choose whether to export with media or without media.
>
> An email will be composed with your chat history attached as a .txt document.
>
> ### Note:
>
> - If you're in Germany, you might have to update WhatsApp before you can use the export chat feature.
> - If you choose to attach media, the most recent media sent will be added as attachments.
> - When exporting with media, you can send up to 10,000 latest messages. Without media, you can send 40,000 messages. These constraints are due to maximum email sizes.

Comment: I know about the export feature. We would like to automate this process and I don't think WhatsApp supports this.

Comment: Perhaps a long shot, but you could consider setting up a Raspberry Pi or spare hardware to automatically run something like this: https://github.com/JMGama/WhatsApp-Scraping

Comment: Interesting! I'll check it out right away. Thank you!

Comment: @Adrian sure! You could also set up your own code running Scrapy or something similar